# How to identify a BackboneJS Model serverside

Tags: backbone.js

I'm just getting my head around BackboneJS, but one of the (many) things I'm still struggling with is how exactly the Models Sync up and relate to the serverside DB records.

For example, I have a Model "Dvd", now I change an attribute on the "Dvd" Model, the Name for example, and then I call save(), how exactly does the server side know what DB record to update? Does Backbone hold the DB row ID or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, typically you will set up your Backbone models so that they have database row IDs for any objects you're working with.  When one of them is brand new on the client side and not yet saved to the server, it will either have a default or no ID, which doesn't matter since the server will be assigning the ID if and when the initial save transaction succeeds.

Upon saving or updating a model item, Backbone expects the server to reply with some JSON that includes any attributes that have changed since the save or update request was made.  In the response to the initial save request, the server informs the client of a newly saved item's row ID (and you can also send along any other information you might need to pass to the client at the same time).

By default, the 'id' attribute of a model object is assumed to be its unique identifier, but backbone lets you change this if you're using a different identifier for the primary key.  Just give your model an `idAttribute` parameter (see the docs for `Backbone.Model.extend()`) to do that.

Meanwhile, either the `urlRoot` parameter or a `url` function can be given to your models to characterize the urls that should be used to send the various ajax requests to the server for a given model.